# How to calculate and plot 3D Fourier transform in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, fft, simulation, differential-equations

I am currently employing a centered finite difference method to simulate the excitation of a circular membrane by a forcing term in Python, and the code is functioning as intended. To further enhance the simulation, I am considering the incorporation of a 3D Fourier transform. This would allow me to analyze the response of the circular membrane at different frequencies, such as when the frequency is set to 257, to observe the excitation of specific normal modes. Could you provide guidance on calculating and plotting the 3D Fourier transform in Python for this purpose?

This is the array where the wave data is being stored

```
u = np.zeros((N_steps, Nr, N_phi))
```

and this is my code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import jn_zeros
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

#%% Parameters
Nr = 50
N_phi = 50
N_steps = 10000
radius = 1
c = 10
dphi = 2*np.pi/N_phi
dr = radius/Nr
dt = 0.0001
CFL=c**2*dt/min(dr,dphi)
print(CFL)



#%% Initial conditions
r = np.linspace(0, radius, Nr)
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N_phi)
R, phi = np.meshgrid(r, phi)
X = R*np.cos(phi)
Y = R*np.sin(phi)

#%% MODE 01
m=0
n=1
frec= jn_zeros(m, n)[n-1]*c/radius

print("la frecuencia es",frec,"modo",m,n)

#frec=257

#%% Stepping
u = np.zeros((N_steps, Nr, N_phi))
k1 = (c*dt)**2/dr**2
for t in range(0, N_steps-1):
    for i in range(0, Nr-1):
        for j in range(-1, N_phi-1):
            ri = max(r[i], 0.5*dr)  # To avoid the singularity at r=0
            k2 = (c*dt)**2/(2*ri*dr)
            k3 = (c*dt)**2/(dphi*ri)**2
            u[t+1, i, j] = 2*u[t, i, j] - u[t-1, i, j] \
            + k1*(u[t, i+1, j] - 2*u[t, i, j] + u[t, i-1, j])\
            + k2*(u[t, i+1, j] - u[t, i-1, j])\
            + k3*(u[t, i, j+1] - 2*u[t, i, j] + u[t, i, j-1])
            if i==12 and j==29:
                u[t+1,i,j]=u[t+1,i,j]+1/5*np.sin(frec*dt*t)

#%% Plot 11
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
Z = u[999]  # Or choose another time step to visualize # Crece hasta 150 maximo en 610
# Recien en 900 empieza a cambiar el sentido
ax.plot_surface(X.T, Y.T, Z, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()

#%% Animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax3d = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Inicializa la superficie 3D
Z_3d = u[0]
surf = [ax3d.plot_surface(X.T, Y.T, Z_3d, cmap='viridis')]
# Set Z-axis limits
u_flat = u.flatten()

maximo= np.max(u_flat)
minimo=np.min(u_flat)
if abs(maximo)<=abs(minimo):    
    ax3d.set_zlim(-maximo, maximo)
else:
    ax3d.set_zlim(-maximo, maximo)

ax3d.set_zlim(-200, 200)
#ax3d.set_title("Frecuencia{} ".format(frec))
ax3d.set_xlabel('X')
ax3d.set_ylabel('Y')
ax3d.set_zlabel('Z')
ax3d.view_init(azim=70, elev=13)

# Function that animates
def update(i):
    index = i * 10
    if index < len(u):
        Z_3d = u[index]
        surf[0].remove()
        surf[0] = ax3d.plot_surface(X.T, Y.T, Z_3d, cmap='viridis')

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(N_steps), interval=10, blit=False, repeat=False)


plt.show()
```

I tried  this

```
#%% Sección de FFT
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
FS= np.fft.fftn(u)



# Calculate the magnitude spectrum along each axis
fouriertime = np.abs(FS.sum(axis=(1, 2)))


plt.plot(fouriertime)
plt.title('Transforamda temporal'), plt.xlabel('Time Step')



subfouriertime =fouriertime[:300]

# Find peaks in the subset
peaks, _ = find_peaks(subfouriertime)

# Plot the spectrum with identified peaks
plt.figure()
plt.plot(subfouriertime, label='Temporal Transform')
plt.plot(peaks, subfouriertime[peaks], 'x', label='Peaks > 0.2e7')
plt.xlabel('Time Step')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.show()
```

But as you see, i do not get a peak at 24.04 hz that is the frecuency of the mode 01

Comment: You need to vectorize the triple for-loop. Until you do, this will be very slow.

Comment: what is going to be very slow? The code is working in a good way and yes maybe is not the most optimal, but is an undergraduate project and for this level, I think that the complexity is okay.

Comment: Welcome Manuel to SO! What @Reinderien mentioned is a useful concept to know about and is often overlooked among non computer science students. Read about time complexity of an algorithm [here](https://victoria.dev/blog/a-coffee-break-introduction-to-time-complexity-of-algorithms/). Since this is more of a FFT question, I would recommend moving this question to [DSP stack exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).